# I have a class of FileDetail which contains FileName,how can I return duplicate filenames within that class

Tags: c#, directory, duplicates

I have the following code which will return the filename of all files within my directory and sub-directories of documents. I would now want to compare files which have identical filenames and see if their size is the same. I am not sure on how I would be able to add duplicate file names to a class and to then compare the filesize of these.

Below is the code I have working so far

```
private static void ListAllDuplicateFiles()
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(rootPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    List<FileDetail> fileDetails = new List<FileDetail>();
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
        FileDetail fileDetail = new FileDetail(fileInfo);
        fileDetails.Add(fileDetail);
    }

    foreach (FileDetail fileDetail in fileDetails)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(fileDetail.Filename);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a list of string to store the names that are duplicate, then use the list of string to do  the comparison that you want

```
private static void ListAllDuplicateFiles()
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(rootPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    List<string> duplicates = new List<string>();
    List<FileDetail> fileDetails = new List<FileDetail>();
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
        FileDetail fileDetail = new FileDetail(fileInfo);
        fileDetails.Add(fileDetail);

        if(fileDetails.Select(f=>f.Filename).Contains(file))
        {
            duplicates.Add(file);
        }
    }
    
    foreach(string duplicate in duplicates)
    {
        //Do what you want with the list of duplicated file details
        var duplicateFileDetails = fileDetails.Where(f=>f.Filename == duplicate).ToList();
    }

    foreach (FileDetail fileDetail in fileDetails)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(fileDetail.Filename);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```